# How to use 'script' in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have this kind of api example and I want to  use this in nodejs.

```
/*
https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/crypto-js/CryptoJS%20v3.1.2.zip
*/

<script type="text/javascript" src="./CryptoJS/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./CryptoJS/components/enc-base64.js"></script>

function makeSignature() {
    var space = " ";                // one space
    var newLine = "\n";             // new line
    var method = "GET";             // method
    var url = "/photos/puppy.jpg?query1=&query2";   // url (include query string)
    var timestamp = "{timestamp}";          // current timestamp (epoch)
    var accessKey = "{accessKey}";          // access key id (from portal or Sub Account)
    var secretKey = "{secretKey}";          // secret key (from portal or Sub Account)

    var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, secretKey);
    hmac.update(method);
    hmac.update(space);
    hmac.update(url);
    hmac.update(newLine);
    hmac.update(timestamp);
    hmac.update(newLine);
    hmac.update(accessKey);

    var hash = hmac.finalize();

    return hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
}
```

But the problem is when I use this in Nodejs, I don't know how to require those CryptoJS.
For example, I downloaded CryptoJS file by google. and it is reading by require.
Even though it is read, I don't know which should I read correctly.
Could you help how to solve this problem?

```
const CryptoJS = require('./CryptoJS v3.1.2/components/enc-base64');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NodeJS (latest version), you don't even need to download an external library or install from NPM.

Nodejs has [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) built-in library.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

var space = " ";                
var newLine = "\n";             
var method = "GET";             
var url = "/photos/puppy.jpg?query1=&query2"; 
var timestamp = "{timestamp}"; 
var accessKey = "{accessKey}";
var secretKey = "{secretKey}";

const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretKey)
                   .update(method)
                   .update(space)
                   .update(url)
                   .update(newLine)
                   .update(timestamp)
                   .update(newLine)
                   .update(accessKey) 
                   .digest('hex');

console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I dont know why you download file from google? There is very useful npm library. find it here and use it.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Comment: Thank you. I did like what you said. It works. well. But the thing is that on 'hmac.update(newLine)' says 'Invalid array length'. Can I solve this problem?